# Visual FoxPro-query with parameters

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

Do somebody know how can i write in SQL language in Visual FoxPro a query with parameters? It doesn't work in the same way like it does in Access and I am a little bit lost here. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of query you're using, either using the built-in SQL engine that queries native FoxPro tables or if it's a query using an external data source.

First for the case of a native query, it's really simple. Since it's a native FoxPro instruction, you can access to every single feature out there, including variables, where you can simply put your user supplied data without worries:

```
LOCAL data                                   &&This could come from user input
data = "hello world"
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column = data  &&Filtered parametrized query
```

The other option is to submit a SQL query for an external server to process, where the query is sent as a text string. In this case, special markers for parameters can be used, matching FoxPro variables, and in turn that would result in a parametrized query sent to the server:

```
LOCAL data
data = "hello world"

LOCAL hConn = SQLSTRINGCONNECT(connectionString)
SQLEXEC(hConn, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column = ?data", "SomeTable")    &&The "?data" parametrizes the query, sending the value separate from the query itself
SQLDISCONNECT(hConn)
```

Comment: m.data to be precise.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Just `data` will suffice and works perfectly. The `m.` prefix is not necesary at all and just creates noise. But will work in any either case.

Comment: I won't go into a discussion. You can read about m. (aka dot) on documents and forums or ask as a question why it is a necessity.

Comment: This is the most correct answer here. In the case of parameterizing a vfp query simply use the variable* directly in the query; if parameterizing a SQL pass-thru query then use the `?<variable*>` syntax. This causes FoxPro to pull the value of `data` from the current scope. *Note: This is also why @CetinBasoz added the `m.data` comment because if there is another workspace selected which has a `data` column Foxpro will always choose that instead of the memory variable

Comment: @nqramjets, while I agree on m.data I don't understand why you think this is the "most" correct answer here. You are claiming you really understood what the OP is asking but OP never made it clear. No where OP said the question was about SQL pass through or native VFP query.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I agree it was not very clear. I took the line "...SQL language in Visual FoxPro a query with parameters" to mean that Lisa was trying to write a SQL query in VFP. **Assuming** that was the case, this answer provides both version of the parameterized syntax, that's all.

Comment: @nqramjets, "Assuming" is the key here:) I assumed Lisa was asking how to use parameters with VBA (as she mentioned access - probably from within access). Otherwise it was too simple to answer. SQL pass through is not the only way to query external sources either. FWIW, I do use VFPOLEDB from within VFP to query VFP datasources a lot and there ?m.data would simply be a  pitfall.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Ahh, that makes sense. I thought she was trying to just do that in VFP, and obviously the syntax is different... Also, I've seen you all over foxite and fox wikis for years, so it's great to finally "meet" you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your question is too broad to provide a simple answer.
The syntax for one query will vary from the syntax to perform a different query.

And Yes, the SQL Query syntax is likely slightly different than M$ Access.

However you can always do a Google search for: **vfp sql query syntax** to find specific syntax equivalents.

Note:  The "WITH" parameters will be in a simple WHERE clause similar to most other SQL Query languages,
Such as   **WHERE Field1 = "ABC" AND Field2 = 235**
but it will be using the VFP language syntax.

Also you might want to spend some time looking at the free, on-line VFP tutorial videos at:  [free on-line VFP tutorial videos](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)
Specifically the one labeled:  **FoxPro and the SQL Language**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, not even shows an example of a parametrized query.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit w3schools.com to see SQL basics. It doesn't work like access, that is true, because access, which is a so called SQL database engine, has its own understanding of the SQL. VFP OTOH is closer to ANSI SQL (IOW closer to SQL Server).

You haven't specified the language you are using, but saying access, I would assume you are trying with VBA. Here is a sample in VBA (excel) using parameters:

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim oRecordset1 As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim oConnection As ADODB.Connection
   Dim oCommand As ADODB.Command
   Dim oParameter1 As ADODB.Parameter
   Dim oParameter2 As ADODB.Parameter


  Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
  Set oCommand = New ADODB.Command

  oConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9\Samples\Northwind"

  oConnection.Open
  oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection
  oCommand.CommandText = "select * from Orders where OrderDate >= ? and OrderDate < ?"

  Set oParameter1 = oCommand.CreateParameter("start")
  oParameter1.Type = adDate
  oParameter1.Value = CDate("1996-08-01")
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oParameter1

  Set oParameter2 = oCommand.CreateParameter("end")
  oParameter2.Type = adDate
  oParameter2.Value = CDate("1996-10-01")
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oParameter2

  Set oRecordset = oCommand.Execute()
  Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (oRecordset)
End Sub
```

Note: Parameters are positional, not named.

Comment: This seems like Visual Basic, but the question was about FoxPro.

Comment: @Alejandro, it is not clear if the question is about VBA or VFP. I got that OP was asking how to query a VFP database with parameters from within VBA. Otherwise it would be too simple to ask.

Comment: Maybe, I got that he's writing VFP code mostly because of the tags and put Access as an example. OP needs to clarify whatever he meants to say.

Comment: @Alejandro, having access as an example suggests the question is about VBA. Otherwise VFP has an SQL that is closer to ANSI SQL than what access' propriety SQL.